# developing a metrics for prioritizing attack patterns based on a standard database for attack patterns(CAPEC)

Tags: dataset, normalization

I have data on attack patterns which has various attributes like severity of attack, attackers skill, attack likelihood all in the form of linguistic values like high, medium and low. I want to develop a metrics for prioritizing these attack patterns based on the above attributes. Should I convert low to 1 medium to 2 and high to 3 or use some other mapping technique.